# Ubuntu script not working in CRON

Tags: bash, shell, ubuntu, cron

I have a very simple bash script

```
#!/bin/bash
count=`ls | wc -l`
mkdir Folder$count
```

This script works when I execute it manually but fails to execute in the crontab. All the permissions on the file for execution are okay.

I have tried the following, put the output of the PATH variable in the crontab entry. Below is my my config in the crontab.

```
PATH=/usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/opt/workspace
* * * * * /opt/workspace/makedir
```

In /var/log/syslog, I could see that the cron executes the script every minute. So what am I missing?

Comment: How do you mean "fails to execute in the crontab"?  What are the errors?  What are the symptoms?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess the working directory of cron is `/`.
add a `cd /path/to/your/working/directory` to your script and it'll probably work.

The default cron executing environment is very limited, but I think `ls`, `wc` and `mkdir` will be found